# Why is my app closing when I press the button?

Tags: react-native, react-redux, expo

My react native app closes without error when the button is pressed. The codes are below. Where did I go wrong? This error started after adding the thumbnail. Previously, the picker was opened with text. I want to add images in it. I am trying to make an application like this.
[Demo Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Se80w.png)

**Error Video:**
[Click Button to Close App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MquGc.gif)

```js
    import React, { useState } from 'react';
    import { navigationService } from '../../services/NavigationService';
    import {
      Picker,
      Platform,
      ScrollView,
      StyleSheet,
      View,
      Text,
      TouchableOpacity,
      SafeAreaView,
      Image,
      TextInput,
      Alert,
      
      
    } from 'react-native';
    import { Thumbnail } from 'native-base';
    export function WithDrawScreen(props) {
    const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState("BITCOIN");    
    return(
      <SafeAreaView>
        <ScrollView>
        <View style = {styles.container}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress ={() => {navigationService.navigate('MyAccount', null);} }>
              <Image style= {styles.imageSt} source={require('../../assets/arrow-left-circle.png')} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <View style = {styles.textView}>
              <Text style = {styles.textStyle}>Yatır/Çek</Text>
            </View>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.container2}>
        <Image style= {styles.imageSt2} source={require('../../assets/Btc3232.png')} />

          <Picker
            selectedValue={selectedValue}
            style={{ height: 50, width: 150 }}
            onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => setSelectedValue(itemValue)}
          >
            <Picker.Item label="BITCOIN" value="btc" />
              <Thumbnail square style={{width: 30, height: 32, marginTop: 5}} source={require('../../assets/Btc3232.png')}/> 
            <Picker.Item label="TÜRK LİRASI" value="tl" />
          </Picker>
        </View>
        </ScrollView>
        </SafeAreaView>
        
    )}


    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        container: {
            flexDirection: 'row',
            backgroundColor: '#131C47',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            height: 50
          },
          container2: {
              flex:1,
              flexDirection: 'row',
              paddingTop: 20,
              alignItems: "center"  
          },
          imageSt:{
            width: 32,
            height: 32,
            marginLeft: 10,
            marginRight: 5,
            marginTop: 8,
            marginBottom: 8,
            backgroundColor: '#131C47',
          },
          imageSt2:{
            width: 32,
            height: 32,
            marginLeft: 10,
            marginRight: 5,
            marginTop: 8,
            marginBottom: 8,
          },
          textView:{
            flex: 2,
            backgroundColor: '#131C47',
            height:50,
            marginLeft:15,
          },
          textStyle:{
            flex: 1,
            fontSize: 32,
            color: "white",
            fontFamily:"Roboto",
          },
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if that is the case but

```
const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState("BITCOIN");
```

should be

```
const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState("btc");
```

Please also note that the 'react-native' [Picker module is deprecated](https://reactnative.dev/docs/picker).

Comment: It's closed again. I'm new to React native. I don't know much. This is how they made the current application.